SAP Report Painter - Using Row Totals in Column Formula
I'm trying to recreate a report painter report that unfortunately, as this point I can't base it off a copy of the original.  (I'm trying to add another component that causes an error in that report) This report has column that uses a percentage based off results in a row formula.
That report has several values available for calculations that start with a Z (which are based off row total calculations). I only see columns available to use for calculations.
Is there a simple way to assign these totals a "Formula Component"
Thanks for any help
Brad
